# Why Enum output is different when assigning value to some of its constant name in c#

Tags: c#, enums, output

Why Enum output is different when assigning value to some of its constant name in c#?

**code:**

```
class Program  
{  
    enum months { jan, feb, march, april, may, june = 100, july, aug, sept, oct = 0, nov, dec };  


    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("January " + months.jan + " " + (int)months.jan);  
        Console.WriteLine("february " + months.feb + " " + (int)months.feb);  
        Console.WriteLine("March " + months.march + " " + (int)months.march);  
        Console.WriteLine("April " + months.april + " " + (int)months.april);  
        Console.WriteLine("May " + months.may + " " + (int)months.may);  
        Console.WriteLine("June " + months.june + " " + (int)months.june);  
        Console.WriteLine("July " + months.july + " " + (int)months.july);  
        Console.WriteLine("Augest " + months.aug + " " + (int)months.aug);  
        Console.WriteLine("September " + months.sept + " " + (int)months.sept);  
        Console.WriteLine("October " + months.oct + " " + (int)months.oct);  
        Console.WriteLine("November " + months.nov + " " + (int)months.nov);  
        Console.WriteLine("December " + months.dec + " " + (int)months.dec);  
        Console.ReadKey();  
    }  
}
```

**output:**

```
January jan 0  
february feb 1  
March dec 2  
April april 3  
May may 4  
June june 100  
July july 101  
Augest aug 102  
September sept 103  
October jan 0  
November feb 1  
December dec 2
```

Why on output of the above code: "months.march" is "dec", "months.oct" is "jan" and "months.nov" is "feb"? Please help me in this?

Comment: Those *are* the values you assigned to the enum `oct = 0, nov, dec`. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum): `the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1`

Comment: Why do you set the enum-values at all (e.g. `june=100`)?

Comment: @SubhamJain why did you set the values of specific enums, like 100 for June? What were you trying to do? Were you trying to create a dictionary perhaps?

Comment: The reason is that under the hood .net uses the numeric values for the enumeration and that the value of `nov` is equal to `feb` ToString() is not called on the enum-variable name directly, but on its value (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,e91b5f6f66834f75). Most logical would be to have unique values for each entry (or work with flags). If the values must remain, you can use `nameof(months.nov)` to ensure you get the value itself

Comment: I'm guessing you are deliberately producing code here just to see what happens. It's behaviour that isn't fully documented (because why would you do this in normal code?), but the "why" can no doubt be found in the source code for enum.

Answer (score 4):

You set some values for your enums which will force the internal value-counter to be reset to the last used value. As you set `october` to be zero, the next enum-value for `november` will be `1`. So Just omit them:

```
enum months { jan, feb, march, april, may, june, july, aug, sept, oct, nov, dec };
```

Having said this multiple enum-values can represent the same integer-value, as in your example `jan` and `oct`, which will both evaluate to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the documentation where it says:

> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.

([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum))

When you explicitly set values for your enum, the next enum increases that value by 1. This also happens when you redeclare a value (as you did with October).

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly based on assumption, but as an attempt to specifically answer your question:

> Why on output of the above code: "months.march" is "dec", "months.oct" is "jan" and "months.nov" is "feb"? Please help me in this?

Your line:

```
Console.WriteLine("December " + months.dec + " " + (int)months.dec);
```

is running a `.ToString()` on an enumerated value. By my reading of the [Enum source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs), we go down the following path:

- `ToString()`
- `InternalFormat`
- `GetName`
- `GetEnumName`
- `GetEnumRawConstantValues`
- `GetEnumData`.

If I'm right (and others are welcome to say if I'm misinterpreting) this appears to build up two arrays, one of values and one of the string representations. **Crucially, only a single string representation can be linked to each value here.**

If the list is looped through in alphabetical order (which would explain why 'dec' is chosen for both 'dec' and 'mar', but 'feb' for 'feb' and 'nov'), only the first valid value is added to the list. Thus, it returns `dec` for `2`, but `feb` for `1`.

Comment: Your assumption fail in this scenario: 
        enum months : long { jan, feb, march, april = 00000000001, may, june = 100, july, aug, sept, oct = 0, nov, dec = 33000000 };